# Two Different Right Hand Grip Rules

Tags: electromagnetism

I have a question about TWO DIFFERENT right hand grip rules I was told about my teacher today and I'd like to have the legitimacy of them confirmed. The first one describes that in an individual peice of wire, if the thumb describes the direction of current, then the other fingers describe the direction of the magnetic field. The second one, which I'm more unsure about, says that in a coil, if the fingers describe the direction of current in the coil, then the thumb points towards the north magnetic pole of the electromagnet. Are both of these correct?

Comment: Not really unclear *what* you're asking, but very unclear *why* you're asking. Both "tricks" are a consequence of the cross product $I \mathrm{d}\vec{\ell}\times \vec{r}$ in the Biot-Savart Law (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biot%E2%80%93Savart_law and links within)

Answer (score 4):

If you consider a coil of wire in a plane, with current going anti-clockwise, and apply the "magnetic field from current" rule to the right hand side of the coil (where the current is flowing up), you will see that your fingers are on the inside of the loop, pointing towards you. This confirms that the magnetic field is pointing towards you in such a configuration (diagram below adapted from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Right-hand_rule)

[image]

And if you hold your right hand over the page so your fingers point in the direction of the current, your thumb is pointing towards you.

Both rules are correct.

I am not sure why you need independent confirmation of this - it's something you can so easily convince yourself of.